# конвертация object[] в int[]

Tags: c#

как конвертировать object[] в int[] или другие типы данных, пример:

object[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};

int[] new_Arr = (int[]) arr; (Как правильно написать код в этой строке , Что конвертация прошла успешно?)

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью LINQ:

```
using System.Linq

object[] objectArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] intArray = objectArray.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

А вообще, стоит использовать сразу `int[]`, если это возможно, а не кастить элементы.